# call local variable in element cause not defined error

Tags: angularjs, custom-directive

I try to create the following directive

```
function sortingTableHeader($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var tableHeaderEles = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('th'));
      angular.forEach(tableHeaderEles, function(tableHeaderEle) {
        var thElement = angular.element(tableHeaderEle);
        var thValue = thElement.text();
        var sortIcon = '<span class="fa" ng-init="abc=' + theValue + '" ng-class="{\'fa-sort\': sortType != abc}">{{abc}}</span>';
        thElement.append($compile(sortIcon)(scope));
      });
    }
  };
}
```

I tried to call theValue variable in the element, it throws an error:

```
angular.js:14525 ReferenceError: theValue is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to call local variable in element?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is it `theValue` or `thValue`! You have defined `thValue`, not `theValue`.

Comment: Thank you so much.... I spent one hour trying to fix that stupid bug.....